# javascript object instantiation to include an array as one of the properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create an object which includes an array stPoints as one of its properties.
I am getting an error message saying that stPoints is undefined. What is the proper way to declare an array property within an object?

this is my code:

```
var temp={stName:"#states.stateid#",stPoints:[]};
```

Comment: The code you have provided is fine. Show us the code that thinks that `stPoints` is undefined.

Comment: here is the rest of the code var stateObj=[];
var stName;
var stPoints;


<cfoutput query="states" group="stateid">
//var temp= Object.create{{stName:#states.stateid#},{ stPoints:[]}};
var temp={stName:"#states.stateid#",stPoints:[]};
 <cfoutput>var coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(#states.latitude#, #states.longitude#);
 stPoints.push(coordinates);
 </cfoutput> 
 
stateObj.push(temp);
</cfoutput>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. You must be referencing it incorrectly.

```
temp.stPoints
```

Answer (score 0):

`var temp={
   'stName':"#states.stateid#",
   'stPoints':[]
};`

However, if the property name is a valid javascript identifier, as in this case, you should not have problem.